# Particle System Slot vs Settings

Tags: particles

Why is the name of a particle system slot different from the name of the particle system settings it contains?

[image]

This is not the same as material slots, where the slot and the material share a name.

Comment: Its like object and mesh relation, you can switch different settings on the particle system like you can change mesh on the object or switch texture on material.

Comment: @Denis, mind writing that as an answer? or can I?

Comment: even the material slot and the material have different names ( and they have the same relation as this )

Comment: @Chebhou, If you change the name of the slot, the name of the material changes with it (and vice versa)

Comment: @ajwood my mistake; I thought they don't

Comment: Could whoever writes that out as an answer explain why the particle-slot/-settings and object/mesh relationship is different from the material-slot/material?

Comment: @ajwood the material slot has different structure because you can apply multiple materials to objects unlike object/mesh

Comment: actually the material slot has a separate name but it is read only and set by blender to match the material name so basically it's the same

Comment: @Denis You can assign multiple particle systems to an object in the same was you can apply multiple materials, no?

Comment: @ajwood you are right, Chebhou gave correct explanation about material slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particle System name is different from Particle Settings name because you can have Multiple setting for each Particle System. By creating multiple settings you can quickly switch between them to see the difference instead of replacing the Particle System.